# Multiple histogram plotly, working time depending on month and event_name

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, data-science

I would like to get a multiple histogram in plotly/seaborn depending on the month and event_name. Please see attached DataFrame (simple example). May you please resolve this tackle ?
[image]

```
data_example = {'event_name': ['verification_1', 'verification_2', 'verification_1', 'verification_2','verification_3'],'working_time_in_hours': [10,300,50,100,50],'month':['April','April','May','May','May']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- this is a straight facetted figure in **plotly** https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/
- your sample data doesn't really have an attribute for **x** so dataframe index has been used

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data_example = {
    "event_name": [
        "verification_1",
        "verification_2",
        "verification_1",
        "verification_2",
        "verification_3",
    ],
    "working_time_in_hours": [10, 300, 50, 100, 50],
    "month": ["April", "April", "May", "May", "May"],
}

fig = px.bar(pd.DataFrame(data_example), y="working_time_in_hours", facet_col="event_name", facet_row="month")
# cleanup yaxis labels
fig.update_layout({ax:{"title":{"text":""}} for ax in fig.to_dict()["layout"].keys() if "yaxis" in ax})
```

[image]